# django ModuleNotFoundError: No module named

Tags: django, python-3.x, module, django-views, django-urls

My Project File :

The code from Views is :
[1]

`from django.shortcuts import render`

```
 def home(request):
return render(request, "home.html", {})
```

The code from urls is :
[2]

```
from django.contrib import admin

from django.urls import path

from firstproject.firstproject import blogs

urlpatterns = [

path('', blogs.views.home, name='home'),

path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

]
```

The Project File is :

the path of manage.py is in 
C:\project\firstproject\firstproject\
the path of home.html is in 
C:\project\firstproject\firstproject\blogs\templates\

when run The Project , showing me these message :
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'firstproject.firstproject'

Answer (score 0):

As i can't really understand your question well, i want to believe you have a python file name firstproject.py where blogs is a name of a class or thereabout.
if this is so, then your code should be like this

```
from django.contrib import admin

from django.urls import path

from .firstproject import blogs
```

If this doesnot work, then share your project directories here (Preferable an image)

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting a ModuleNotFound error, then you should check in the following in manage.py:

```
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'news_project.settings')
```